# Tafsir 2:178 Sura al-Baqara, what dose '..female for the female..' means?

Tags: tafseer, hudud

I maybe read this ayah many times but I didn't noticed it very well, until last night, me and my friend which he don't believe in anything.

> *He told me*:
>  Suppose I killed your wife or your sister, shall you kill
>   me or you will kill my wife/sister?
>  *I Said:*
> You must be killed.
>  *He said:*
>  Ok, I am agree with you, but your
>   religion doesn't say that, see Al-Baqarah [**[2:178]**](http://quran.com/2/178) says **{... free
>   for the free, the slave for the slave, and the female for the
>   female...}**.

I stopped there because I couldn't say anything, I told him I don't give any excuses for my religion, but I will see what dose it means and why this ayah came down(Sabab nzul).
I searched through Google, but I couldn't find much details.

So, my question is:
*Suppose you were me, how would you answer him?*